# Java primitive declaratiron

Tags: java, syntax, operators, declaration, primitive

Given the following code snippet:

```
int i = 0;

int y = + ++i;

System.out.println(y);
```

The result is 1. Why is this a valid declaration? Can anyone explain what is =+?

Comment: Not a question I'd care about, because no one should write code like this.  But my guess is ++i = 1 is straightforward enough, and the extra plus sign is a unary plus, as if you'd written int i = +1;  Not necessary, but acceptable.

Comment: Is this a question from a test? Doesn't look like something you'd encounter in actual code...

Comment: Indeed it is actually an OCJP (formally known as SCJP) test question. Best to understand it anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
int y = + ++i;
```

The first `+` in this line is simply the unary `+` operator (see: [Assignment, Arithmetic, and Unary Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html)). It does nothing. It's similar to the unary `-` operator. The line above is equivalent to:

```
int y = ++i;
```

which increments `i` and then assigns the new value of `i` to `y`.

Answer (score 2):

Here `+` indicates the value is positive or not,i.e. `unary` operator and if you changes the value to `-` then the answer will be `-1`. i.e. `int y = - ++i;` will give `-1`.

Answer (score 2):

The first plus after the equals sign is the sign of the value.
So it means it is a positive number.

`int y = - ++i;` would return `-1`

Answer (score 0):

[Java guarantees](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7.1)  that it will be evaluated `left-to-right`. Specifically, ++ has `higher precedence` than +. So it first binds those, then it associates the addition operations left to right